How to randomize UUIDs in an APFS container?
I made a copy of an APFS container using dd. That was some time ago and by now the containers (on separate physical devices) each have different data on them, which I'd prefer to preserve without having to shuffle them. (It's only become an issue recently because I want to run a machine with both disks connected simultaneously.)
I've come across the system-provided apfs.util, whose help output indicates that it's capable of doing what I want, with the -s option, but I've been unable to get it to work. The tool always immediately exits with no error/standard output, and exit code 253.
What I've tried:

Use synthesized disk as identifier .../apfs.util -s /dev/disk3
Use partition on the physical disk as identifier .../apfs.util -s /dev/disk2s2
Each of the above, with all volumes of the container unmounted (diskutil umountDisk disk3)
Each of the above, after diskutil ejecting the synthesized disk (which didn't actually remove the synthesized disk, or its volumes, from under /dev or output of diskutil ap list)
Use a volume on the affected container, contrary to instructions .../apfs.util -s /dev/disk3s3
All of the above, inside a full root shell instead of appended to sudo

Any idea how to run the command, or figure out what the issue might be?

Try executing the command while booted to Internet Recovery.

I also recently cloned an APFS container that has macOS Catalina on it to a larger SSD using dd. I tried apfs.util -s under many different conditions:

macOS Recovery (catalina)
macOS Sonoma Installer USB (OCLP)
connected to another mac (Sonoma) with Target Disk Mode

I also tried the same after deleting APFS snapshots resizing the APFS container. They all exit without any output, but echo $? gives 252 or 253.
In all cases, diskutil apfs list disk# shows same UUIDs before and after apfs.util -s.
I hesitated to try the same using a Mojave Installer USB that I happen to have, because the older os version may be incompatible with later versions of APFS.
With the Mojave installer, it still gives exit code 253.
But this time all the UUIDs have changed (except the physical store uuid, which is already different from the old drive).
Don't forget to rename the uuid folder in the Preboot volume if you cloned a system drive.
diskutil mount diskDsP
cd /Volumes/Preboot
ls
mv old_uuid new_uuid

